# How to access the /myservlet example servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jira, jira-plugin

I created a jira 7.6.1 plugin (using `atlas-create-jira-plugin`) and a servlet module (using `atlas-create-jira-plugin-module`). When defining the servlet module, I sticked to the suggested defaults - my `atlassian-plugin.xml` looks like this:

```
<atlassian-plugin ...>
    ...
    <servlet name="My Servlet" i18n-name-key="my-servlet.name" key="my-servlet" class="my.package.servlet.MyServlet">
        <description key="my-servlet.description">The My Servlet Plugin</description>
        <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet>
</atlassian-plugin>
```

When I run jira, the plugin and the module are correctly displayed in the add-on management.

How can I access the new servlet?

I tried these urls, but none of them works:

- http://localhost:2990/myservlet (gives a generic 404 page)
- http://localhost:2990/jira/myservlet (gives a Jira 404 page)
- http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/myservlet (gives a Jira 404 page)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Jira plugin developer documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/servlet/#accessing-your-servlet:)

> Your servlet will be accessible within the Atlassian web application
>   via each url-pattern you specify, beneath the /plugins/servlet parent
>   path.

In this example, it should be:

- http://localhost:2990/jira/plugins/servlet/myservlet